# Adding Include Files to the Add Controller T4 Templates in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, t4

Is it possible to add include files within my custom t4 templates for the "Add Controller" dialog box?

I have tried doing:

```
<#@ include file="Helpers.tt" #>
```

This is what you would typically do in t4 but this does not seem to work.

Currently i have resorted to throwing all my helper functions in the footer of my templates but this has already become abit of a maintenance nightmare.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the same problem I had.  You will need to create a base class for the T4 template and extend it with your own.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078858/t4-templates-error-loading-the-include-file-ef-utility-cs-ttinclude-returned-a/8210150#8210150) for my solution.

Comment: I've just had time to update my templates and the base class solution worked a treat and allowed me to remove alot of repeated code. Thanks