# T4 templates error: loading the include file ef.utility.cs.ttinclude returned a null or empty string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4

I have overridden the controller generation T4 templates (`ControllerWithContext.tt`) as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx).
I would like to take advantage of the code helper utilities found in `EF.utility.CS.ttinclude` as used in the POCO model generator T4 template.  Therefore I copied the following lines from my `Model.tt` to my `ControllerWithContext.tt`.

```
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
```

However, when I try to add a controller I am getting the error message

> Loading the include file 'EF.utility.CS.ttinclude' returned a null or empty string

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126242.aspx), this error is because the included file is blank, which it clearly isn't because it works with `Model.tt`

The only difference I can see is that the overridden `ControllerWithContext.tt` does not have a Custom Tool defined, whereas the `Model.tt` has it set to `TextTemplatingFileGenerator`.

My workaround is to copy the functions I need from `ef.utility.cs.ttinclude` into my `ControllerWithContext.tt`, which in itself threw up more errors but which were easily solved.

How can I include T4 templates without a custom tool defined?

Answer (score 10):

Following @DustinDavis' advice, and using the invaluable information found on [OlegSych's site](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/04/t4-template-design/), here's what I did:

- Created a new project called CodeGenerationTools.
- Added project references to

  - System.Data.Entity.Design
  - EnvDTE
  - System.Data.Entity
  - Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.10.0

  For this last reference I had to install the correct version of the Visual Studio SDK
- Copied the EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude file into the project.
- Renamed it CodeGenerationTools.cs
- Edited the file and convert all `<#@ import namespace="<name>" #>` to `using <name>;`
- Deleted the opening and closing `<#+ #>`
- Added the directive `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating;`
- Extended the class:

  ```
  public class CodeGenerationTools : TextTransformation
  ```
- Override the `TransformText` method

  ```
  public override string TransformText() {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
  ```
- Added empty constructor

  ```
  public CodeGenerationTools() {
      _textTransformation = DynamicTextTransformation.Create(this);
      _code = new CSharpCodeProvider();
      _ef = new MetadataTools(_textTransformation);
      FullyQualifySystemTypes = false;
      CamelCaseFields = true;
  }
  ```
- Finally, build this project.

The next steps took place in the main project
- Edited the T4 template file.
- Changed template directive to

```
    <#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" debug="false" inherits="CodeGenerationTools"#>
```

- Added the directives

```
    <#@ assembly name="C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CodeGenerationTools\CodeGenerationTools\bin\Debug\CodeGenerationTools.dll" #>
    <#@ import namespace="CodeGenerationTools" #>
```

All of which now means I can use the helper methods found in EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude in my own T4 templates, and I have the means to add my own helper methods which will be available to all projects.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Visual Studio 2012 or 2013, install [this EF tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40762) to resolve the error.

Comment: Your answer saved me. really thanks for help. You have to be answer #1

Comment: still issue for me

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the template processor isn't even trying to get the include file (as confirmed using ProcMon). You can reproduce this using any template, not just the EF.Utility.CS.ttinlcude

Not sure why you need the code but you can always build your own base class, just have it inherit from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTransformation and then put in all the code thats is in the EF.Utility file. Then set the inherits directive to point to your new base class and then you can access those methods from your template.

Comment: Thanks.  As I mentioned I wanted to take advantage of the `CodeGenerationTools` class found in `ef.utility.cs.ttinclude` in my own T4 templates.

Comment: Just follow what i suggested and you can, just not by using an include (at least for now because it seems to be broken)

Comment: @DustinDavis: are you saying that `<#@ include file="..." #>` simply doesn't work?