# T4 templates and using include directive for common code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4

I have overridden the controller generation T4 templates as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx).

On examining the AddView templates (`Create.tt, Delete.tt, Details.tt, Edit.tt, List.tt`) I saw that there is a lot of common code in a class feature block at the end of all these files.  So, I thought I'd be clever and put all the common code into an external file and simply include this file in all the templates.

```
<#@ include file="common.ttinc" #>
```

However, this does not work.  The following error is displayed

> Loading the include file 'common.ttinc' returned a null or empty string. The transformation will not be run.

Is there a technique whereby I can include class feature blocks containing helper methods in other T4 templates, or would I have to create a base TextTransformation class with all the common methods and have my T4 templates inherit from that?

#### Edit

This might actually have the same answer to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078858/t4-templates-error-loading-the-include-file-ef-utility-cs-ttinclude-returned-a) on T4 templates.  However, I would still like to know the techical reasons why we can't just include class feature blocks with helper methods in T4 templates.

#### Edit 2

I should add that 'common.ttinc' is in the same directory as the view templates and there is no Custom Tool defined because I only want the template to be processed when accessed through the Add Controller/Add View wizards

Answer (score 2):

Currently, ASP.Net MVC uses a custom host for T4 rather than the standard Visual Studio one and the custom host does not support the standard include behavior, so includes in MVC don't work.

I don't know if MVC supports base classes, but if it does, that would be another approach.

Logging a connect bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio is a good option here.

Answer (score 1):

```
Loading the include file 'common.ttinc' returned a null or empty string. 
The transformation will not be run.
```

That error means T4 engine didn't find the include file. IIRC T4 engine begins by looking in the same folder as the .tt file. With VS2010 SP1 it should also be possible to use $(ProjectDir) like expansions as well.

You can define class feature blocks in a separate include file, I do that all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, still relevant. Agreed with @FuleSnabel, but better than *should*, expansions like $(ProjectDir) and $(SolutionDir) *do* work in VS2015. I tend to declare my libraries of shared tt code in a "Common" project, and for other products or projects that need it, I create a tt file that include the shared tt file, passing in the templatefile path so I can create a local file, and a namespace so the generate code relates to the current project.

```
    <#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
    <#@include file="$(SolutionDir)..\..\Company\trunk\src\csharp\Company.Common.Interfaces\Generation\EnumMethods.tt" once="true"#>
    <#@ output extension=".g.cs" #><#
    GenerateEnums(this.Host.TemplateFile, "Company.Product.Interfaces");
    #>
```

Note: this works for me as all my products/libraries can be accessed via a relative path and all developers in the team have the same relative paths, but I'll run into issues when working on branches, because that ***trunk*** folder in the path is bad.