# T4 Visual Studio 2010 include linked T4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linked-list, include, t4

Here's one. I have a bunch of T4s in one project / solution. This is a framework with support code and T4 templates.

In a different solution, I want to use this framework, but have the support classes / T4s remain in the original solution.

In the new solution I link to the support code and T4s (add existing / link). Now in the new solution I have a T4 which needs to include the linked T4. It has something like this:

<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ include file="..\Models\DALContextGenerator.tt"#>
<#@ output extension=".cs"#><#
Generate("..\Models\Model1.edmx");

## >

In this case, DALContextGenerator.tt is in this solution, but is linked to the real DALContextGenerator.tt in a different solution. WHen I run the T4 I get an error ("Failed to resolve include text"). If I reference the physical location it is fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Ray

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the T4 engine uses the template file as a root and is unaware of the Visual Studio Solution and Solution items. If you're using a Visual Studio link to a file somewhere else this information is only stored in the project file. The T4 engine looks up the include-path relative to the T4 file. That's why referencing the Visual Studio Link relatively fails. But referencing the include file either with its absolute path or a relative one pointing to the physical file succeeds.

Here are some ideas how to address your problem, but there is no "smooth" solution I can think of:

- Use a hard link between the original include file and a file located next to the template file (command line: `mklink /H source target`)
- if you are using a source control system (like svn) you can work with external directories without duplicating your originals
- Have a (meta-)T4 template that generates the actual T4 template with the proper paths based on the information you get from Env.DTE Visual Studio Model

Comment: Nico, Thanks for that. I solved it by defining an environment variable with the physical path of the original, and having the other T4s use that in the include directive.

Answer (score 0):

Old but relevant question, I think the same as this other thread, where I posted a reply, using expansions $(ProjectDir) and $(SolutionDir): https://stackoverflow.com/a/42785952/1948625