# EF6 / Cannot build project with auto-generated *.tt files ("Failed to resolve include text for file:.......\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude.")

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

### Background

I got simple CRUD app using **Entity Framework 6** created in **Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise**. Schema / models / DB stuff were created using `*.edmx`

### Problem

After cloning reposiroty to different computer (or removing all of auto-generated `*.cs` files) **while trying to build / rebuild** I got following errors for every `*.tt` file:

`Failed to resolve include text for file:[PATH TO APP DIRECTORY HERE]\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude.`

`Loading the include file 'EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude' returned a null or empty string. The transformation will not be run.`

**Manual re-generation of files works fine** (via opening popup menu on `*.tt` files and clicking `Run Custom Tool`)

**This file exists** in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude`

**but I have absolutely no idea why VS is looking for it inside project path.**

**Is it a bug / problem with VS / EF6 configuration?**

I've tried:

- re-installation of Entity Framework Tools
- adding 'ASP.NET and web development'

**None of these helped :(**

Similar thread:

[How can I resolve this error: Loading the include file 'EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude' returned a null or empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999633/how-can-i-resolve-this-error-loading-the-include-file-ef-utility-cs-ttinclude)

**Hardcoding correct path in auto-generated `*.tt` files IMO is not a proper solution**

Answer (score 1):

After follow [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2017), I've added 'IncludeFolders' tag to resolve 'EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude' and the 'ItemGroup' to invalidate DevEnvDir in template processing. 
This's how the .csproj file looks like:

```
...
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <TransformOnBuild>True</TransformOnBuild>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
    <IncludeFolders>$(DevEnvDir)Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes</IncludeFolders>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <T4ParameterValues Include="DevEnvDir">
        <Value>$(DevEnvDir)</Value>
        <Visible>False</Visible>
    </T4ParameterValues>
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you explain modifications you did?

Comment: After follow [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2017#to-edit-the-project-file), I've added <IncludeFolders> tag and the <ItemGroup> to invalidate DevEnvDir in template processing.

Comment: Ah. OK but it would be better if you edit your answer and  include this  explanation into it